# How does Spring inject values into variable annotated by @HeaderParam?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aop, aspectj

I am trying to dive deep into the mechanics of the Spring Framework. The following piece of code achieves inserting "token" parameter from HTTP request into the `token` variable:

```
@POST
@Path("/")
Response saveOne(@HeaderParam("token") String token, UserDTO uDTO) {
}
```

## How can I achieve the same?

And what tools do I need? Is it done using AOP? Say, I would like to come up with a custom annotation `@MyAnnotation` and any **parameter** or **field** marked by it would be customized by some logic. Example:

```
public class MyClass {
   ...
   @MyAnnotation
   private String myVar1;

   public void myMethod(@MyAnnotation myParam1) {
   ...
   }

   ...
}
```

When I create instance of MyClass or when I **autowire** it in my Spring application I would like to have a piece code that triggers right before I use the `myVar1` variable and/or when I call the `myMethod(param1)`. I want to set the *annotated* variable to whatever value I want. **How can I do this?**

What makes me wonder is how Spring does do it in case of the `@HeaderParam`? I basically need the same functionality.

Comment: You asked a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70102796) before already with regard to annotated fields, put a bounty on it, and I [answered it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70102796/1082681) already. Besides, from an AOP perspective it makes a difference if you annotate a field or a method parameter. For annotated fields, like I said before, you need native AspectJ. For annotated parameters, you might be able to use Spring AOP, if your target class is a Spring-managed component/bean.

Comment: BTW, isn't `@HeaderParam` rather JEE than Spring? I am not a framework (JEE, Spring) user, but chances are that your JEE container does the magic in this case, rather than Spring. Spring provides `@RequestHeader`, but that one works for parameters only, not for fields.